# CSS animation not working in mac

Tags: css, macos, safari

I am with problem in mac/safari, 2 css animation not working in refresh screen.

- div should do right scroll left.
- image resize.

To scroll I am using:

```
.overlay {
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.83;
  -webkit-transition: right .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: right .5s ease;
  -o-transition: right .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: right .5s ease;
  transition: right .5s ease;
  position: relative;
}
```

And for image resize:

```
.resize {
  animation: animationIncrease .5s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: animationIncreaseMac .5s infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: animationIncrease .5s infinite alternate;
  -o-animation: animationIncrease .5s infinite alternate;
  -ms-animation: animationIncrease .5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes animationIncrease {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
}
```

In Chrome/Firefox/Ie it's right. Only in Mac/Safari not working... if I stop click, it's right. Suggestions?

https://jsfiddle.net/z6r9oakw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define another animation in your `-webkit-animation` prefix : `animationIncreaseMac` but I didn't see this animation. You only declare `animationIncrease`. You should probably add this if you want your `animationIncreaseMac` working (but no need two differents animations for the same animation. Just add your keyframes prefix for your `animationIncrease`)

```
@-webkit-keyframes animationIncreaseMac {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry @smdsgn. I have just code here, and not working too. Only just forgot for the post.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of your problem ?

Comment: =/ .. in fiddle right in mac!!! but, in my page not working... only I click in stop button!

Comment: The fiddle works for me too on mac safari. So the problem is on your page. What do you mean by "only I click in stop button". I don't see any stop button in your code.

Comment: browser stop button. In page load, image are stopped... if click in browser stop button it's work.

Comment: Sorry but it's not easy to understand. You mean your page load forever ? This why you need to click on your browser stop button ? I don't think css animations are the problem. Be sure all your script are correctly loaded and check if you have any error message in your console.

Comment: I not need click in stop button, but... it's work. I go check script again! Tks smdsgn!